# quicktime play/pause keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, quicktime

Is there any ability to start playing and set pause for video in quicktime by keyboard hotkey.

Now i'm doing window switch and then clicking on space key to achieve it. Is there any hot-key for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my MacBook air, it has those keys already on the keyboard, F7 fast reverse, F8 play/Pause, F9 fast forward :)

If you don have MacBook Air keyboard, then you can use the

- Space bar for Play/Pause

Comment: oh :) you were rigth :) I even did't suppose that these keys will be used for audio and video ;) thanks.

Comment: you r welcome :)

Comment: and feel free to give me some Cudos for a correct answer ;) You must know I collect them.

Comment: @user44516 what is it Cudos ?